# Running Python from React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, api-design

Update: At the moment I'm looking at updating ScriptPath and Option

I have a working python script and would like to call it from a React Component

I tired following the direction from python-shell documentation the best I could.

The exact error I get is provided as a screenshot below.

Is there a more efficent way to do this ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { PythonShell } from "python-shell";

class RunPy extends Component {
  runPy() {
    console.log("Im here");

    PythonShell.run("../Py/py.py", null, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("finished");
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={this.runPy}>
        RunPy
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default RunPy;
```

[React Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Qk3.png)

Comment: React is a client-side language...

Comment: [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) is specifically for `node.js` code, not for running in the browser (Reactjs).

Comment: Hmmm okay I need to restructure then...